Deno Equivalent of `npx tsc --watch`
I typically debug code in typescript using npx tsc --watch so it can tell me where my variables aren't lining up, or not imported correctly.
Is there an equivalent in Deno?

Type-checking in "watch" mode is not yet supported, but a request for the feature exists at the following GitHub issue and you can track progress there: denoland/deno#14858 — Add watch mode for deno check
